# How to check if email already exists in db with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am doing application in CodeIgniter. I don't know how to compare email against db in CodeIgniter, please any one, help me.

Controller

```
public function signup()
{
    $this->load->view('signup');

}
public function savedata(){

$this->load->library('form_validation');        
$this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'firstname', 'required'); 
$this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'lastname', 'required'); 


if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) // Only add new option if it is unique
{       
    $result = $this->account_model->insert();
    if($result > 0)
    {
    $data['message'] = "Added successfully";    

    $this->load->view('signup',$data);
    }
    else
    {
    $this->index(); 
    }
}
else
{
    $this->load->view('signup');
}
}
```

How to check whether email already exists or not?

Comment: where do you pass email?

Comment: Check the `is_unique` validation rule

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a rule:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'callback_rolekey_exists');
```

In the same Controller:

```
function rolekey_exists($key) {
  $this->roles_model->mail_exists($key);
}
```

In Model,

```
function mail_exists($key)
{
    $this->db->where('email',$key);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html/#callbacks)

Comment: There already is the `is_unique` rule, no need to make your own

Comment: and moreover you need to return `true/false` from callback function. and define `error message for your custom callback`.... `is_unique` is best approach though as mentioned by @DamienPirsy .

Answer (score 9):

Suppose, you have `user` table and `email` column. So you have to add this line in form validation

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
```

**Note**
And need an unique index in your `email` column

check [Documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference)

Answer (score 2):

Best Way

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
            'email', 'Email', 'valid_email|required|is_unique[usr_user.user_email]',
            array('is_unique' => 'This %s already exists.')
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //in controller    
public function usernameExist($username)
{
    $user = $this->Model-> usernameExist($username);

    if ($user) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message(
            'usernameExist',
            'Username  is already exist.'
        );
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: the same apply to email.I just made the funcion username.Type this in controller

Answer (score 0):

```
function username_Exist($key)
{
    $this->db->where('username', $key);
    $query = $this->db->get('signup');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

//type this in model

Answer (score 0):

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'User', 'trim|required|callback_username_Exist');
        //type in controller in form validation
```